# Is it possible for two TCP connections to have the same SEQ/ACK number?

Tags: tcp

Say we have many TCP connections established between various ports. Is it possible for two of these connections on different ports (eg. 50000 -> 80, 40000 -> 80) to have identical SEQ or ACK numbers?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The chance for this to happen for the next established communication is n / 2^32 where n is the amount of tcp communications, and n > 0

Credit to Ron Maupin in comments of the questions.